# must the imperative programming paradigm comply with the forward declaration rule?

Tags: paradigms, imperative-programming

In a exam in my course of Language Programming was this question:

Is the next program valid in a imperative programming?

```
   int a = 0;
   z = a + 2;
   int z = 3;
```

was not specified or grammar, or syntax, or anything extra. My answer was YES because eventually there may be a language, a syntax and a grammar design for wich is valid use z without declare it and  're-declarate' z later. My grade was 0.0 but I still find it unfair. could help to clarify the issue?. Thank.

Comment: There are many imperative languages; some of which don't require an explicit declaration and others which hoist declarations (and I'm sure there are many more aspects to consider). However, remember to answer *in context of course material* - even when saying "YES". Hand-waving ("eventually there may be") is not a strong enough justification and does not demonstrate the course concepts.

Answer (score 1):

You were marked unfairly.

Paste the following code snippet into the debugger console of your browser:

```
(function() {
    var a = 0;
    z = a + 2;
    alert(z);
    var z = 3;
    alert(z);
})()
```

Comment: +1 for the counter-example although this is sort of cheating because JavaScript "hoists" the "declaration" making  `function () { return x; var x = 2; }` *semantically identical* to `function () { var x; return x; x = 2; }` (note that both functions always return `undefined` as the assignment does not happen!)

Answer (score 1):

Considering your course is titled "Language Programming", I imagine "imperative programming" has to be interpreted strictly. Quoting the current tag-wiki for [imperative](/questions/tagged/imperative), we have

> Imperative programming is a paradigm of expressing the logic of a computer program or computation by explicitly describing its control flow in terms of statements that change a program state.

Arguably the most *reasonable* interpretation of the given C-like code is that `int z = 3;` is a variable declaration (and assignment), and the line `z = a + 2;` is thus usage before declaration. Assuming this is a legal program, this does not follow the imperative paradigm since its control flow was not explicitly described i.e., it wasn't sequential.

---

That said, you are right that since there was no specified grammar or syntax, the program could literally do anything, including what you specified, calculate π, or display a pink elephant on the monitor. Obviously, we need to draw a line somewhere. Given that your course is titled "Language Programming," I think that critically evaluating how reasonable your specification for a possible language is a good way to go.

We have plenty of languages where simple use of a previously unknown variable implicitly declares it, so that's quite reasonable. However, the "re-declaration" part of it, I find quite unusual and confusing and believe that it would be a bad language feature. I'm unaware of any major programming language which allows it<sup>1</sup>.

Therefore, I believe that your answer of "YES" in that narrow circumstance should at best have been a side note in an answer where the main answer was "NO".

---

1. Similar, but unrelated cases, are where different variables have the same name but different scopes, and where the same variable can be assigned objects of different type.